# Baffling Zsh behavior on = (equal sign) precedes a Zsh $variable

Tags: variables, zsh, variable-expansion

When a `=` sign precedes a Zsh $variable expansion, I get the following behavior:

```bash
% m=$PATH;  echo =$m=
zsh: /usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin= not found
```

Quite perplexing. What is happening, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've discovered `=` filename expansion.

Per [14.7.3 ‘=’ expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion) from the zsh docs:

> If a word begins with an unquoted ‘=’ and the `EQUALS` option is set, the remainder of the word is taken as the name of a command. If a command exists by that name, the word is replaced by the full pathname of the command.

To disable this behavior, unset the [`EQUALS`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Description-of-Options) option:

```bash
unsetopt EQUALS
```

Here's an example of both behaviors:

```bash
$ m=date

$ setopt EQUALS
$ echo =$m
/usr/bin/date

$ unsetopt EQUALS
$ echo =$m
=date
```